# Getting the names of the parameters of a constructor

Tags: ruby, reflection

I want to retrieve the names of the parameters in a constructor. Given the following code:

```
class Something
  def self.do_something(a, b); end
  def initialize(a, b); end
end
```

I get:

```
Something.method(:do_something).parameters
# => [[:req, :a], [:req, :b]] 
Something.method(:new).parameters
# => [[:rest]]
```

Why is `Method#parameters` returning `[[:rest]]` in the case of `new`, and how can I get the constructor parameters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you ask about the parameters of `Something::new`, you will get the parameters of `Something::new`. If you want to know the parameters of `Something#initialize`, you need to ask for `Something#initialize`:

```
Something.instance_method(:initialize).parameters
# => [[:req, :a], [:req, :b]]
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because the arguments that `Something.new` takes are all optional. You can pass whatever numbers of arguments to  `Something.new`. `Something.new` will create an instance using none of the arguments given, and the whole set of arguments given to it are passed to `Something#initialize`, and it is there that you have defined the method with particular numbers of arguments.

To get what you want, you need to directly consult `Something#initialize`:

```
Something.instance_method(:initialize).parameters
# => [[:req, :a], [:req, :b]]
```

Comment: Good one... :) I didn't think till that point.. So i deleted my answer.. :( But you should have your gift..i.e. *+1* ..